# Evoluent vertical mouse manager won't install on Windows-7

Tags: windows-7, installation, mouse

Just bought left-hand, wired, regular size Evoluent mouse 4 from Amazon.

When I try to install

evoluent_mouse_manager_v5.0.msi

And I get this error 1001. Could not load 'sorttbls.nlp

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT WORKING!

Solution was to uninstall existing Framework 4...
and then re-install 4.5.1 from Google of "Microsoft 4.5.1 download".

Now, I can reprogram my wonderful vertical mouse buttons.

MOUSE TIP:

You can more easily lift and move mouse around by grabbing its back half, which has more friction.